# arcgis runtime sdk for wpf deployment

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, deployment

I was developed map application using "arcgis runtime for wpf" and this app works fine on my pc, but when I published my project with visual studio and install the application on the client machine the application go down. what is the simplest and the correct way to deploy applications uses Esri controls like 'map and legend'?